# How to set width of view to be half width of its superview in Xcode 6

Tags: interface-builder, autolayout, xcode6

Trying to understand autolayout in Xcode6/Interface Builder.

How can I set the width of a view to be half (or like 10% or whatever) width of its superview in Xcode 6/Interface Builder using constraints?